# Compare range of pd.Series between train set and valid set

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I got a train set and valid set as below:

```
>>> train
    A    B
0   1  300
1   5  600
2   2  450
>>> valid
      A    B
0  1500  300
1     4  600
2     2  450
```

For every columns in train set, I would like to know if the range of `valid[col]` is inside of the range of `train[col]` , which means `if max(valid[col])<=max(train[col]) and min(valid[col])>=min(train[col])`. In this example:

```
>>> func(train,valid)
          A    B
    0  False  True
```

Beside building a `for` loop to check each column in train set each time, is there any better way to build this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [59]: %paste
def f(col):
    return (train[col].max() >= valid[col].max()) & (train[col].min() <= valid[col].min())

## -- End pasted text --

In [60]: train.apply(lambda c: f(c.name))
Out[60]:
A    False
B     True
dtype: bool
```

as a DF:

```
In [63]: train.apply(lambda c: f(c.name)).to_frame(0).T
Out[63]:
       A     B
0  False  True
```